# Вырезать определенные слова из текста и поменять местами

Tags: java

Есть текст вида

> "Вкладыш","Crank", " Compressor", "Piston crown","Bushing","Crankease","Bushing"
>
> "Втулка", "Starting air valve", "Piston crown","Chain pipe, hole", "Exhaust gas", "Exhaust valve", "Cylinder liner"
>
> "Выхлопной клапан","Palm, fluke", "Piston crown","Starting air valve","Exhaust valve", "Exhaust gas manifold", "Exhaust valve"
>
> "Выхлопной коллектор", "Crankease", "Exhaust gas manifold","Expansion
> joint","Nozzle", "Exhaust valve","Exhaust gas manifold"

Мне надо поменять местами последнее слово в строке (как пример - Слово "Bushing" на "Вкладыш") и так для каждой строки.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Покажите пример где вы пытались решить данную задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А в чем проблема? Ищем первое слово, ищем второе слово.

Поиск можно делать через `indexOf` и `lastIndexOf` (от 0 до первой запятой - первое слово, от последней запятой до конца строки - второе слово):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "\"Вкладыш\",\"Crank\", \" Compressor\", \"Piston crown\",\"Bushing\",\"Crankease\",\"Bushing\"";
        int i1 = s.indexOf(",");
        int i2 = s.lastIndexOf(",");
        String result = s.substring(i2+1, s.length()) + s.substring(i1, i2+1) + s.substring(0, i1);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Пример на [ideone](https://ideone.com/gXAUpR).